# C++: Datastax CassFuture to BoostAsio Awaitable

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-coroutine, datastax-c++-driver

I would like to turn the CassFuture Object from [Datastax's C++ Driver](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/basics/futures/) to a Boost Asio Awaitable Object. The problem is it seems like this conversion could induce additional overhead as I would effectively be wrapping a future around another future. Does anyone have any smart ideas or useful insights or worst case a way to approach this that minimally wastes computational effort?

I have considered the idea of creating a for loop where when it checks the future and the future yields no result (ie. no error or result) that it simply passes priority back to the io_context, but this seems inefficient and arbitrary versus leaving and the scheduling to the built in io_context scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the callback handler. From the linked page:

> A callback can be set on a future to notify the client application when a request has completed. Using a future callback is the lowest latency method of notification when waiting for several asynchronous operations.

I have not delved into the documentation to find out exactly which threads could invoke the callback. If you want to completely isolate from the implementation detail, you could always post a handler onto the Asio service.

To be completely Asio compatible (including `asio::use_future`, `asio::use_awaitable` etc), you could implement an async initiation function using the [Completion Token](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html) pattern.

Comment: Can you give an example or some psuedo code? Completion tokens generally just generate another thread without reusing existing infrastructure and then signal the asio engine.

Comment: Completion tokens practically never create a thread (you wouldn't need completion tokens then anyways). The linked example recklessly says that this is just for example, not for production code (the reason is that any other "realistic" example would require one to understand a specific, nonstandard, asynchronous API which would be counter productive for documentation.

Comment: Incidentally that's also the key reason why it's not super easy or effective for me to show you an implementation for your specific API (Datastax) because it will require me to install, configure, test with that library which might require more dependencies or even accounts, subscriptions etc. If you put something working on e.g. GitHub i might have a look

Comment: I guess my question is as follows:

Comment: I am assuming though boost::asio::promise could be used to act as a solution to this where in the callback I have the Datastax API set the value of the promise and in my boost application I async_wait for the promise correct?

Comment: Whoa. That looks nice. I have not seen `asio::promise` before. I was thinking along these lines, so you don't need that: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a85c22f14b45418d Perhaps it can be made easier with the experimental promise facility.

Comment: Yeah my problem is that because it is an experimental feature it is hard to understand how to use it properly., its limitations, and ultimately its underlying implementation.